# How to move the qtip tip based on the mouse over

Tags: jquery

I am using qtip for the tool tip and i moved the tool tip based on the cursor. Shall i call function to move the arrow pointer from left to right and then right to left dynamically. Hoe will i change the tip left position from 10% to 95% on the mouse move.

```
jQuery('.fire-object a img').each(function() {
                jQuery(this).qtip({
                    // within an each() loop, $(this) refers to the trigger
                    content: jQuery(this).attr('title'),
                    style: { 
                          width: 110,
                          padding: 5,
                          background: '#FFFFFF',
                          color: 'black',
                          textAlign: 'center',
                          border: {
                             width: 7,
                             radius: 5,
                             color: '#FFFFFF'
                          },
                          tip: 'bottomLeft',
                          name: 'dark' // Inherit the rest of the attributes from the preset dark style
                     },
                    position: {
                            my: 'left top',
                            target: 'mouse',
                            viewport: $(window), // Keep it on-screen at all times if possible
                            adjust: {
                                x: 10,  y: 10
                            }
                         },
                    hide: {
                        fixed: true // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding ocassionally when tracking!
                    }
                });
                });
```

[example](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/effects/multitooltip)
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is you're current code?

Answer (score 0):

qTip2 is out. Features: [Mouse Tracking](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#mouse)

Comment: This already i did. In mouse tracking i want to call the function to move the arrow from left to right and then right to left when i move mouse

Comment: please check the link above